# Can I obtain French citizenship if my mother's great-grandfather was French?

Tags: france, citizenship, nationality

My mother is Egyptian and her great-grandfather was French. She sent the papers (certificat de nationalité française) to France before she died to claim French nationality. I am her only son.

Can I claim French nationality based on her request, or should I apply from the beginning again. Is there a chance that I can get French nationality now?